# Get Chromium On Ubuntu 20.04 WITHOUT SNAP!

Tags: ubuntu, chrome

I was wondering how to install Chromium WITHOUT SNAP! When I install Chromium it installs Snap so how do you do this?

Comment: Seems like a dupe of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/chromium-without-snap

Comment: There are clear directions here, not worthy of really typing an answer as it's pretty straight forward: https://fosspost.org/tutorials/chromium-deb-package-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: This might be a duplicate to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/chromium-without-snap

Comment: Install Linux Mint. Ubuntu is done and for exactly this reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install it as a flatpak:

`flatpak install flathub org.chromium.Chromium`

Comment: That just results in the following (for armhf at least):
Looking for matches…
error: Nothing matches org.chromium.Chromium in remote flathub

Answer (score 0):

Part One: Download Available Dependencies.

1. Download these:

```
sudo apt install libgcc1 libmpx2 gcc-8-base
```

Part Two: Get .deb files of Chromium

1. Install VirtualBox
2. Run Ubuntu 18.04 in it
3. Download Chromium (and dependencies) with `download-only` flag

```
sudo apt-get --download-only install chromium-browser chromium-browser-l10n chromium-codecs-ffmpeg-extra
```

4. Go to `/var/cache/apt/archives` and the .deb files will be there.
5. Copy the deb files into a shared folder between the guest and the host OS.
6. Download and install the packages.

Part 3: Disable Updates in Update Manager or other Update Software

1. Running

```
sudo apt-mark hold chromium-browser
```

will disable the Updates. You will only be able to install them manually.(From new .deb packages from 18.04).

Comment: This seems overly complicated. And you won't get security updates.

Comment: Only Chromium is going to be on pause. You can get .deb's from 18.04 to update it manually. If you update it from here, it will install as a snap.

Comment: Did you already read https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204571/chromium-without-snap ? That approach seems simpler and more secure to me

Comment: No Freaking way.. people. This is not the way to use a browser. Just download if from the Debian repo.